# Jquery sortable inline-block elements jumping

Tags: jquery

I have the problem of jumping elements on sortable jquery function. They are inline-block width % widths.

I searched this problem up on stack but all I found was to use `float:left;`. I tried this but I still have a jump. Somehow the width is slightly increasing when you pick up the element causing it to push everything. Here is my jsfid

https://jsfiddle.net/143eh4gx/

Comment: You have to post relevant code in question itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a width for all LIs, don't use inline styling:

```
#visuals>li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Sortable plugin is using placeholder element which in your code as no width defined.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I didn't know this was causing the issue. Much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the `sortstart` event for this, if you wish like so:
`$("#visuals").on( "sortstart", function( event, ui ) {
    ui.placeholder.css("width","0");
});`
from [jquery documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start)